# Items in flex container overflows parrent element in x-axes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to apply ellipsis inside chips when the chip content is too long. But currently the chip overflows the container.

[image]

Sample code is here: https://codepen.io/SebastianBusek/pen/OJjbQRP

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="chip">
    <span class="chip__label">This is a chip, chip, chip, chip, chip, chip, chip, chip, chip, chip, chip!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="chip">
    <span class="chip__label">Chip & Dale </span>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.chip {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* margin-right: 0; */
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.chip__label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Erase the following CSS properties:

- `height: 32px` from `.chip`
- `white-space: nowrap` from `.chip__label`

Answer (score 0):

use "flex-wrap" on the parent, this will wrap the items onto the next lines